# mutate and truncate functions in r not producing desired output

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some date data in the format Start_year = 2018/19, 2019/20, 2020/21 etc. I want to put it in the format 2018, 2019, 2020, as integers, for a group by clause later in the code.

```
select_data <- data %>%
  select(Product, Start_year, Number, Amount) %>%
  mutate(Avg_paid = Amount/Number)%>% #This works fine
  mutate(Start_year_short = as.integer(str_trunc(Start_year, 4, c("left"))))
```

The error message I get is:

> Problem with `mutate()` column `Start_year_short`.
> `Start_year_short = as.integer(str_trunc(Start_year, 4, c("left")))`.
> NAs introduced by coercion

If I take the mutate out and do

```
Start_year <- as.integer(str_trunc(Start_year, 4, c("left")))
```

I get an object not found error instead.
I really can't work out what's going wrong.

Comment: add `filter(is.na(Start_year_short))` after to see where the NAs are being added, I imagine you have some rows in a different format

Comment: always advisable to check out if the function you take is giving you the expected result in the first place. `str_trunc("2018/19", 4, c("left")) # [1] "...9"` so no suprice if you make that an integer it produces a `NA`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead `as.integer(substr(Start_year, 1, 4))`

Comment: Thanks, it's working now!

Comment: I'm still having some problems as it's throwing an object not found error up further down the code. The Start_year_short variable is the subject of a group_by clause in a function to  give the average payments by year, but when I run it on the data set I get Error in group_by(Start_year_short) : object 'Start_year_short' not found

Answer (score 2):

How about this simpler truncation method:

```
data.frame(Start_year) %>%
  mutate(Start_year_short = str_replace(Start_year, "(\\d+).*", "\\1"))
```

With conversion to integer:

```
data.frame(Start_year) %>%
  mutate(Start_year_short = as.integer(str_replace(Start_year, "(\\d+).*", "\\1")))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use stringr::str_split instead to be more flexible with the length of the numbers.

```
Start_year = c("2018/19", "2019/20", "2020/21") 
Start_year <- as.integer(stringr::str_split(Start_year, pattern="/"))
```